# Can I use my old laptop keyboard as a keyboard for my newest one?

Tags: windows, laptop, keyboard, bluetooth, wireless-keyboard

Some keys on my new laptop's keyboard are not working (F4,F5,F6), and I'm wondering if I can use my old laptop as a Bluetooth keyboard. Can I do that?

Are there any other solutions?

Lenovo ThinkPad t560

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found the solution:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460 this one if you want to do that with two windows laptop.(which is my case)

> Mouse without Borders (http://aka.ms/mm) is a product that makes you the captain of your computer fleet by allowing you to control up to four computers from a single mouse and keyboard. This means that with Mouse without Borders you can copy text or drag and drop files across computers.

Supported Operating Systems:

> Windows 10, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2016
>
> Windows 10, Windows Server 2016, Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 (**32/64 bit**). .Net 4.0 & up.

Installation Instructions:

> Download and run the installer on each of your machines. The Mouse without Borders setup experience will be launched after installation. Follow the instructions to configure Mouse without Borders. NOTE: The same version of Mouse without Borders must be run in the machines, old version can be uninstalled in Control Panel or by just running this command: msiexec /uninstall {D3BC954F-D661-474C-B367-30EB6E56542E} /qr. Visit http://aka.ms/mm for help & questions.

And then there is [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy), if you want to connect two laptop with different os.

Comment: Actually your answer does not answer the question you asked, it asked about using it as a bluetooth keyboard, you need to edit your question to ask for other solutions to your problem.